# Adding days to date string

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, invoice

I'm using WooCommerce Invoice PDF plugin which is a plugin for an e-shop within Wordpress.

The invoice plugin does not have any "due date" function so I tried to create one myself.

```
<?php echo $this->get_woocommerce_pdf_date ( $order_id,'ordered' ) ; ?>
```

Here is the string which gathers the information from the order. It collects and displays the day the order was placed. I would like to add **+ 20** days to that string but haven't been able.

I have very little knowledge on PHP so I would REALLY appriciate any help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.  You can construct the object with any date string, I used `2014-01-15` in my example.  Then you can [`::modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) it and get the string by using [`::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).  Check the documentation for other formats, but I used `Y-m-d`.

```
<?php
$date_string = '2014-01-15';
$date = new DateTime($date_string);
$date->modify('+20 days');
$date_string = $date->format('Y-m-d');

var_dump($date_string);
// string(10) "2014-02-04"
?>
```

If you get your date's string with the `get_woocommerce_pdf_date()` function, you can integrate this like so:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($this->get_woocommerce_pdf_date($order_id,'ordered'));
// Modify and format the date object to your liking.
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But this code just gave me isn't connected to the day the order was placed right? The problem is, some customers may want to download the invoice later on and the generated due date will be from the day the customer downloaded the invoice and not the original order date?

Comment: You can use this with any day, my example uses the String `$date_string` which is `2014-01-15`.  However, you can replace this with any logic to get your order date..it looks like you may want `$date_string = $this->get_woocommerce_pdf_date ( $order_id,'ordered' ) ;`

Comment: WOW, thank you! It almost worked perfectly :)

Only problem is it is showing: string(10) "2014-02-04"

I just want it to show: 2014-02-04,

Comment: Use [`echo`](http://us1.php.net/echo) not [`var_dump()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).  I use `var_dump()` in my example so OP knows what type of variable it is (in this case, a string like you wanted.